# display control doesn't have checkbox

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, database-design

I have a lot of checkboxes (with yes/no fields in the underlying tables) and lately Access has been crashing a lot.  After some research it seems null values in the checkboxes could be to blame, so I set out to follow Allen Browne's instructions (http://allenbrowne.com/NoYesNo.html) for replacing them with number fields.  Everything was going great until I got to the step where I set the display control to 106 (checkbox).  This is not an option in the table and I don't understand why.  I set my table up like he stated but I only have the option for a textbox, listbox, or combobox.

I also tried just typing 106 into the Display Control field, but it gives me an error that it isn't an item on the list.  In his article, he mentions to fix the error above to use SetPropertyDAO(), but I have no idea what that means, how to do it, or where to do it.  Do I built it in code somewhere?  The link he has brings you to a script where he uses that to fix his printers or something.

Comment: Null values for checkboxes cannot "crash" Access, whatever that means. And set a control (checkbox?) to 106 doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Gustav: see http://allenbrowne.com/bug-14.html . Not a crash (in Access 2010), but a query that doesn't work as it should. -- The `DisplayControl` property is set to  106 to show a checkbox for a number column in datasheet view. -- All that said, I doubt that this will solve JHT's crashes.

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks. And right, most likely the issue is rooted elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Close your table.

Open Immediate Window with Ctrl+G

Paste the code:

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs("Table1").Fields("Field1").Properties("DisplayControl") = CInt(acCheckBox)
```

Replace table and field name to your names.

Run the code by putting the cursor at the end of the line and hit Return.

If you get an error, open the table in design view, and set the display control to something (it doesn't matter what), save and close, repeat.